# what's the easiest way to set a custom height for a mui chip for versions < 5.0?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on app that uses MUI v.4.11.  I need the ability to set a custom height for a Chip.  size='small' is too big and I need to specify a shorter height.

I know how to do this with v.5.0+ via the "sx" prop. But I'm currently constrained to a lower version.  What would be the easiest way for me to set the Chip height given my app's current version constraint?

Answer (score 0):

In v4, you can extend the [css](https://v4.mui.com/api/chip/#css) class `.MuiChip-root`, to add your custom height:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  chip: {
    '&.MuiChip-root': {
      height: theme.spacing(0.5)
    }
}));
```

In your react component:

```
const classes = useStyles();

return <Chip className={classes.chip} ... />
```